# Using overloaded >> to create objects from file is creating blank objects (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-overloading

So I've got a >> overload set up that pulls labels and chunks of text (images) from a file:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Image data) {
    std::string line;
    std::string full_image;

    getline(is, line);
    data.SetLabel(line);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.GetImageSize(); ++i) { // Stores each full image as a single string
        getline(is, line);
        full_image += '\n' + line;
    }
    data.SetImage(full_image);
    
    return is;
}
```

I've been able to verify that this is working properly because if I stick a print statement at the end for `data.GetLabel()` and `data.GetImage()` the correct strings are outputted.

In a different class I've got this function which is using the overloaded >> to create a list of Image objects (one for each label/image set):

```
void NaiveBayesTrainer::ReadTrainingData(std::string filepath) {
    Image data(image_size_);
    std::ifstream input_file(filepath);

    if (input_file.is_open()) {
        while (input_file >> data) { // Using overloaded extraction operator
            training_data_.push_back(data);
        }
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("File not found");
    }
}
```

But for whatever reason the Image objects getting pulled out of the file (data) are coming out empty. As in, calling `data.GetLabel()` or `data.GetImage()` right before `training_data_.push_back(data)` returns a blank string.

Is there a reason why the operator overload is correctly setting the object's attributes but those updates aren't being passed into the object I'm using to create the list?

Answer (score 4):

The argument `Image data` is *a copy of* what is passed and modification to that will not affect what is passed in the caller.

You should add `&` after the `Image` in the argument (so that it becomes `Image& data`) to have it pass a reference and modify `data` in the `NaiveBayesTrainer::ReadTrainingData` function.

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. I had moved my operator overload to a new class and didn't notice that I hadn't carried that over. Thank you so much!